# In jQuery, which is faster, a selector, or an equivalent function, or does it depend?

Tags: jquery, performance, selector

I've often wondered about the use of selectors versus equivalent functions in jQuery. By this I mean statements that comprise the same components that return identical result sets, but are constructed differently.

Take the following example:

```
alert($("#FundManager1>option").length);
alert($("#FundManager1").find("option").length);
```

*(Note: the intention is for two equivalent queries - If these are not always the same, I would be grateful if you could point this out)*

So, given the example above, is there any real difference in speed/performance? Obviously, the former is shorter, so will result in fewer uploaded/downloaded bytes, but I’m not really interested in that at the moment.

Comment: In CSS, `>` is a (direct) child selector. Therefore, your code above cannot be guaranteed to yield the same result sets.

Comment: You're right, but assuming `#FundManager1` is a `<select>` element, the result will be the same.

Comment: @DouweM Provided that you're not using `optgroup` s (and will not use them in the future), yes :)

Comment: You should compare with `.children('options')` instead of `.find('options')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say the first is faster, as it parses only one CSS selector and only looks for children, where the second one has to parse two, plus has to look for all descendants.

But I wouldn't bother for something so small. As JavaScript is really fast in WebKit and Gecko, and still relatively fast in IE, no-one will ever notice the difference.

---

From what I can see by looking at the jQuery/[Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) source, both pieces of code do the same internally.

First `document.getElementById('FundManager1')` is executed ([Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) is smart enough to know that's what `#FundManager1` means), and then the search for `option` is done using that as context. The only difference between the two pieces of code is the use of the `>` selector, causing [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) to search for just the context's direct children, and not all descendants. I assume this faster, as only one level of DOM hierarchy has to be explored.

---

Another edit:

The text above only applies to browsers that don't support the `document.querySelectorAll(css_selector)` method! In browsers that do (WebKit and Gecko, maybe Opera?) this method is used instead of [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), so that all CSS selector parsing is done by the browser itself, instead of the jQuery framework, which I'm sure is a lot faster.

Comment: Nice answer. (filler goes here)

Comment: Diving into / Analyzing other people's code is always fun ;-) Especially when it's good code.